# Google Drive API OAuth 2.0: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I enabled the Google Drive API in my personal GCP, set up my OAuth2 consent screen, and downloaded my credentials.json file. I'm now running this code from the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) in Colab:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute the code, I am prompted to login via Google's OAuth sign-in page, to give my program access to my Google account. I click Allow, then immediately see this page:
[image: Error screen]

I've redone this without a VPN or firewall with no luck, and I don't know if this is a problem with my OAuth or creds setup in the Project. Thoughts?

Comment: Try deleting the port parameter from `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` The default port is 8080, so if you have something already using that port, try a number above 1023 and less than 65535. The port number 0 is invalid.

Comment: I tried this with various ports between 1023 and 65535, with port 8080, and also without the port parameter. No luck unfortunately :( But it's something I can look deeper into if it's the source of the error.

Comment: `run_local_server()` starts a local webserver. Something is going wrong and the server is not starting (AFAIK). Do you see any error messages, etc? Edit your question with more details on how you are running your code, etc.

Comment: I fixed the error by running it locally in PyCharm instead of in Colab.

Comment: I'd suggest you to post an answer with the solution you found.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running in PyCharm. VSCode also works. For whatever reason, Colab continues to throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a solution:

When run_local_server() opening browser, copy the url and use private browsing to login with this link.

It work for me.

Comment: Welcome Lier! Happy to have you here. A few things. If you look at the other answer you can see that the original poster answered his own question. Consider adding more detail to answers particularly if they are old. Also, you mention a link and there isn't one, you can edit you answer and add one if you like. There are some etiquette standards on Stackoverflow, you can find them here https://stackoverflow.com/conduct